# KVO not working: message was received but not handled

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I got the following error when playing around with KVO. Does it only work with subclasses of UIViewController?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<sort.object: 0x100a074e0>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: name
Observed object: <sort.User: 0x100a06bb0>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = Test;
}
```

The code are as below:

```
import Foundation

class User: NSObject {
    dynamic var name: String?
}

class object: NSObject {
    func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        print("Name changed")
    }
}


var user = User()
var ob = object()
user.addObserver(ob, forKeyPath: "name", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

user.name = "Test"

try user.name = "Test 2"
user.removeObserver(ob, forKeyPath: "name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1416553-observevalue), the name of the method is `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)`. Note `of:`, not `ofObject:` as you have. Your method is not an implementation of the required method. I believe you'll need to mark the properly-named method with `override` (and the fact that the compiler let you get away without that was a sign that you had the name wrong).